# play framework call helper function from another template

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a helper file utils.scala.html which looks like below:

```
@renderTableRow(columnTag: String, columns: Seq[String]) = {
<tr>
@for(column <- columns) {
    <@columnTag>
        @column
    </@columnTag>
}
</tr>
}
```

I want to call this helper function from rest of my view files to create table headers.

```
@import views.html.mycommon.utils

@renderQuotesTable() = {
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
       @utils.renderTableRow("th", Seq("Name", "Date of Birth", "Age"))
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
```

}

But, I get the following the error

value renderTableRow is not a member of object views.html.mycommon.utils.

what am I missing here?

Comment: I think it's the import, but I'm not sure. Try: @import views.html.mycommon._ OR: views.html.mycommon.utils._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import the declared functions of another template. Execute `sbt doc` and in the generated Scala Doc is no clue of renderTableRow in the util object. "renderTableRow" is wrapped into the apply method as you can see in the generated source for the template: "target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/views/html/mycommon/utils.template.scala".

For every function you want to use in another template you hava to create a template or a function in a real Scala singleton object.

Comment: thanks, i ended up taking this route. but, it seems very limited from the language perspective.