# Including reusable blocks from a template into another template

Tags: playframework-2.0

I would like to use a reusable block from a template in my another templates. How can I do that? More specifically:

I have a template views/main.scala.html containing this tag

```
@logo_header = {
    <div id="logo-container">
       ...
    </div>
}
```

an I have another template views/errors/notFound.scala.html where I would like to include the logo_header tag from main template. I try @main.logo_header, or @main.logo_header() but the compile always says:

> value logo_header is not a member of object views.html.main

I have looked in the official [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTemplateUseCases) where they describe including, but I can't understand why it not works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've done something slightly different to the usage mentioned in the documentation. In the documentation, the reusable tag is declared in its own file. What you're trying to do is declare a helper function in one view template and then try to call it from another template. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129357/926710), a function is only visible to the view template in which it was declared.

What you need to do is move your logo header markup out into its own file:

**views/_logo_header.scala.html**

```
<div id="logo-container">
   ...
</div>
```

Then reference it as follows:

**views/main.scala.html**

```
<html>
    ...
    _logo_header
    ...
</html>
```

I've given the new file a name with a leading underscore as this is a common naming convention that marks the file out as containing a snippet of HTML rather than a full HTML document.

Finally, I've assumed that your logo header snippet doesn't need to take in any arguments. If it does, you can sprinkle in some Scala as mentioned in the documentation:

**views/_logo_header.scala.html**

```
@(arg1: String, arg2: String)
<div id="logo-container">
   ...
</div>
```

**views/main.scala.html**

```
<html>
    ...
    _logo_header("foo", "bar")
    ...
</html>
```

Comment: So basically, when I need reusable html components (headers, footers, logos) for templates, I have to create its own template for each of them??

Comment: @Behnil - Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @avik. I have one last question. Is the views/tags folder somehow special? Or do they just choose it in the documentation?

Comment: No, it's not special. All your view templates need to go in the `views` package, but below `views` you can define subpackages and organise your templates anyway you choose.

Comment: By the way if you look at the documentation page I've posted in the question, there is a section "Include" with this phrase "You can just call any other template you like (or in fact any other function, wherever it is defined)" So I really don't get it, but your answer is helpful.

Comment: I understand your confusion. The inclusion of the word _function_ in that section of the documentation is a little misleading. What they're trying to say is that you can import `template A` from `template B`, regardless of which packages the two templates are in. What you can't do however is call a function declared in `template A` from `template B`.

Comment: But they call @common.sideBar() in the example and not @common(something), so in my point of view, they call common's function.

Comment: couldn't it all alternatively work with helpers and imports as defined [in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ScalaTemplates)?